# Elasticsearch sync/update after MongoDB document update with Mongoosastic

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using MongoDB, Mongoose, Elasticsearch and Mongoosastic on a Node project. I have a MongoDB Atlas database and a local Elasticsearch database which are mapped together. When I create a new Document in MongoDB it is created in ES as well, and when I delete it in Mongo it is deleted in ES too. So everything works until this point.
What I did next is, I added an update route to update specific documents in Mongo. They do get updated but the changes are not reflected in ES because I might be missing something. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Here is the Model/Schema in `donation.js`:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const donationSchema = new Schema({
  donorUsername: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  bankName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  qualityChecked: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  usedStatus: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

donationSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 9200
});

const Donation = mongoose.model('Donation', donationSchema , 'donations');

Donation.createMapping((err, mapping) => {
  console.log('mapping created');
});

module.exports = Donation;
```

**Here are the create and update functions/routes in `donationController.js`:**

```js
const donation_create_post = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const donation = new Donation(req.body);
  donation.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/donations');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const donation_update = (req, res) => {
  const filter = { donorUsername: req.body.donorUsername };
  const update = {  bankName: req.body.bloodbankName,
                    qualityChecked: req.body.qualityChecked, 
                    usedStatus: req.body.usedStatus };
  Donation.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
    .then(result => {
    res.redirect('/donations');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Added `{new: true}` in `Donation.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true})`.